# What is the appropriate value for UDP port?

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I'm creating a php script for listening incoming data from user. The idea is that user will be able to send UDP packet remotely to their browser and show it on browser.

The script works fine when tested on my localhost by using xampp. After uploading my script in the server, it fails to bind socket connection everytime. I tried port number 50000, 5000, 561, 61 and many others but failing.

Here's my php script, mostly taken from [php's website](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php)...

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    if ($socket == FALSE) {
        echo 'socket_create failed'.socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."\n";
    }

if(!socket_bind($socket, $ip, $port)) {
        socket_close($socket);
        echo 'socket_bind_failed';
}

   socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 255, 0, $from, $port);
```

So, I decided to look into well known udp port as shown [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/port-list), but seems that all is already used up by certain application. My question is, what is the appropriate value for UDP port?

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to bind?

Comment: @DevZer0 Are you saying that it is a privilege problem, not port number?

Comment: @Joni My echo message, which is 'socket_bind_failed'

Comment: I mean the error message from the operating system. You already use the proper functions to get it when creating the socket, why not when calling bind?

Comment: i retreat my comment, i was under the impression that you are creating a `listen` socket

Comment: If you are using a shared hosting service, they may not allow you to bind arbitrary ports on their servers - many don't want any connections aside from their own managed servers available to the outside, for security reasons.

Comment: @Amber I thought the script actually open a local port on users' ip?!

Comment: PHP runs on the server. Any port binding it does is on the server. The IP argument of `bind()` is simply to support computers that have multiple IPs and thus could listen/connect on any of them.

Comment: @Amber I see. Seems like I'll be having hard time with hosting services to provide certain port number to be open. I'll think of an alternative way then. Thanks.

Comment: You probably should investigate why the bind is failing. Most of the time bind fails because hte specified port is already in use. Since you tried with multiple ports numbers, it is likely that is not the case.

Comment: Anything above port 1024, as anything under that are often reserved by the OS and some times require an escalated permission level to get too.